# Handling ProgressBar's Value change with UIAutomation

Tags: microsoft-ui-automation

How can I be notified when ProgressBar's Value changes with .NET UIAutomation framework? I dont see such property in AutomationElement class.

Comment: `AutomationPropertyChangedEvent` with `ValuePattern.ValueProperty.Id` not working?

Comment: Do you have an example code?

Answer (score 1):

I drew this sample directly from the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.automationpropertychangedeventhandler%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1), changing only the property:

```
AutomationPropertyChangedEventHandler propChangeHandler;
/// <summary> 
/// Adds a handler for property-changed event; in particular, a change in the value 
/// </summary> 
/// <param name="element">The UI Automation element whose state is being monitored.</param>
public void SubscribePropertyChange(AutomationElement element)
{
    Automation.AddAutomationPropertyChangedEventHandler(element, 
        TreeScope.Element, 
        propChangeHandler = new AutomationPropertyChangedEventHandler(OnPropertyChange),
        ValuePattern.ValueProperty);

}

/// <summary> 
/// Handler for property changes. 
/// </summary> 
/// <param name="src">The source whose properties changed.</param>
/// <param name="e">Event arguments.</param>
private void OnPropertyChange(object src, AutomationPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    AutomationElement sourceElement = src as AutomationElement;
    if (e.Property == ValuePattern.ValueProperty)
    {
        // TODO: Do something with the new value.  
        // The element that raised the event can be identified by its runtime ID property.
    }
    else
    { 
        // TODO: Handle other property-changed events.
    }
}

public void UnsubscribePropertyChange(AutomationElement element)
{
    if (propChangeHandler != null)
    {
        Automation.RemoveAutomationPropertyChangedEventHandler(element, propChangeHandler);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using FlaUI for Automation. I have a WPF progress bar. Want to Retry until its visibiility is Collapsed. Not able to access the property. Help?

Comment: @Apoorv I'd create a new question, showing what you have already.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60553908/getting-the-visibility-of-a-progress-bar-in-a-wpf-application-using-flaui-automa