# Getting the visibility of a progress bar in a WPF application using FlaUI Automation

Tags: c#, wpf-controls, microsoft-ui-automation, flaui

I am automating a **WPF** app using **FlaUI**. I have a **progressbar** that is **Inderminate**. Once the progressbar gets **Collapsed**, The **UI** is loaded. I want to implement a `Retry` mechanism on the ProgressBar `Visibility` but I am not able to find the correct `property` through `FlaUI`

```
private ProgressBar LoadingStatus => _uiAutomation.FindElement("ShowProgress", Automation.FindBy.Id).AsProgressBar();

<ProgressBar AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ShowProgress"
                Grid.Row="1"
                Height="4"
                Margin="0"
                BorderThickness="0"
                IsIndeterminate="True"
                IsTabStop="False"
                ToolTip="Contacting Server, Please Wait..."
                Visibility="{Binding IsServerActive, Converter={StaticResource MwBoolToVisibilityConverterReverse}}" />
```

I want to implement a `Retry.While((LoadingStaus_Is_Collapsed)=> )};`but seems like I don't have access to the `visibility` property.
How can I get it done?

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: yes I did. Posting the answer

Comment: @FrancescoB. please find the answer posted below

Comment: Glad to see you worked it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property that works here is `IsOffScreen`. The UIA framework provides this property as Visibility is a `WPF` property and not `UIA`.
`IsOffScreen` returns True if the element is not currently on the screen else returns `False`.
This is how I used it

```
public bool LoadingStatusVisibiltity()
        {
            _logger.Info("Retrieving data from the server.Please wait!");
            if (LoadingStatus.IsOffscreen)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```